# How to use hapi js on Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, hapi.js

I try to learn from [an example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/template-handlebars) to use express together with  handlebars on firebase.

For the express way, we can send the "app" instance directly to the "functions.https.onRequest" like...

```
const app = express();
...
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    ...
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

[See live functions](https://authtest-a45aa.firebaseapp.com)

As my understanding it's working because "express"  act like http-node, so it can respond "http plain".

Comparing to **hapi**, here is hello-world

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ 
    host: 'localhost', 
    port: 8000 
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path:'/hello', 
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        return reply('hello world');
    }
});

server.start((err) => {
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

From the hapi example, is it possible to use hapi on firebase cloud function?

Can I use hapi without starting a server like express?

Comment: You should use hapi or express with fire base. Fire base Handels routing for you so there is no need for an routing framework. Keep your functions light weight. If you want to render handlebar templates just require handlebars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code was straight forward as i mixed the express API that used by Firebase with hapijs API, thanks to the blog given by mister @dkolba
You can ivoke the url hapijs handler by going to 
http://localhost:5000/your-app-name/some-location/v1/hi

example: http://localhost:5000/helloworld/us-central1/v1/hi

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server();
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

server.connection();

const options = {
    ops: {
        interval: 1000
    },
    reporters: {
        myConsoleReporter: [{
            module: 'good-squeeze',
            name: 'Squeeze',
            args: [{ log: '*', response: '*' }]
        }, {
            module: 'good-console'
        }, 'stdout']
     }
};

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/hi',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply({data:'helloworld'});
    }
});
server.register({
    register: require('good'),
    options,
}, (err) => {

    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

});



// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
exports.v1 = functions.https.onRequest((event, resp) => {
    const options = {
        method: event.httpMethod,
        url: event.path,
        payload: event.body,
        headers: event.headers,
        validate: false
    };
    console.log(options);
    server.inject(options, function (res) {
        const response = {
            statusCode: res.statusCode,
            body: res.result
        };
        resp.status(res.statusCode).send(res.result);
    });
    //resp.send("Hellworld");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the inject method (last code example): http://www.carbonatethis.com/hosting-a-serverless-hapi-js-api-with-aws-lambda/

However, I don't think that this is feasible, because you would still need to hold onto the response object of the express app instance *Google Cloud Functions* provide to http triggered functions, as only `send()`, `redirect()` or `end()` will work to respond to the incoming request and not hapi's methods (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Answer (score 2):

A few changes are required in order to get compatible with hapijs 18.x.x

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi')
, functions = require('firebase-functions');

const server = Hapi.server({
  routes: {cors: true},
});

server.register([ 
  {
    plugin: require('./src/plugins/tools'),
    routes: {
      prefix: '/tools'
    }
  }, 
]);

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: (request, h) => {

    return 'It worlks!';
  }
});

exports.v1 = functions.https.onRequest((event, resp) => {
  //resp: express.Response

  const options = {
    method: event.httpMethod,
    headers: event.headers,
    url: event.path,
    payload: event.body
  };

  return server
    .inject(options)
    .then(response => {
      delete response.headers['content-encoding']
      delete response.headers['transfer-encoding']
      response.headers['x-powered-by'] = 'hapijs'
      resp.set(response.headers);
      return resp.status(response.statusCode).send(response.result);
    })
    .catch(error => resp.status(500).send(error.message || "unknown error"));
});
```

Comment: Why are you deleting the above two headers and adding and new header?

Comment: in order to prevent double gzip encoding being applied to our response